# Upload video to specific channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

is there a way to upload videos through the Youtube API to a specific channel that I'm administrating.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

From what I see in the documentation the parameters **onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel** is reserved to Youtube partners. Does this mean that I can only upload videos to my personal channel and not to one of my pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per documentation, you are correct. **`onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel`** is only available for Youtube Partner only. If there is a way to be authorized that is when you do a [transfer of ownership of the account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4628007?hl=en&rd=1) but this should be done by the owner himself.

Reference related SO questions:

- [YouTube API - how to specify which channel to upload to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628318/5995040)
- [YouTube v3 API upload to channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30006793/5995040)

Hope this helps.